# Make Vibrator.vibrate do nothing when phone is muted - Android

Tags: android, mute, vibration

Is there a method that makes the vibration not work through `Vibrator.vibrate` method if the phone ring state is `mute` so that I do not check it manually?

Answer (score 4):

check the states and do the work needed

```
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "cannot vibrate already muted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
        Toast.makeText(this, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }
```

Comment: I do know this solution, but my point was that is it possible to make it stop vibrating automatically, I mean it just takes the settings of the user and stop vibration if he does not it to vibrate even if I call `vibrate`